# Is it possible to set the select columns through custom ransacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I would like my users to select the columns of table they want to view. I have read through some code but do not understand how to user ransacker. How can i set the select through a custom ransacker?

```
ransacker :columns do |parent|
....        
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is to use the [attribute_fields](http://rdoc.info/github/ernie/ransack/Ransack/Helpers/FormBuilder#attribute_fields-instance_method) or the [attribute_select](http://rdoc.info/github/ernie/ransack/Ransack/Helpers/FormBuilder#attribute_select-instance_method) form helper inside your search form. Checkout the [advanced code example](https://github.com/ernie/ransack_demo/blob/master/app/views/users/advanced_search.html.erb) on Github, which does something similar, adding select boxes for the fields you want to search on.

Custom [ransackers](https://github.com/ernie/ransack_demo/blob/master/app/models/user.rb) are used to make special searches over several columns and tables, and you have to define them in [Arel](http://rdoc.info/github/rails/arel/master/file/README.markdown).